# Display results in Macaulay2 using text.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, math-software, macaulay2

I use Macaulay2 to compute Hilbert series. But the results in Macaulay2 are of the following form:

```
       2      3       4       5       6        7        8        9        10        11        12       13      14
1 - 27T  + 56T  + 165T  - 792T  + 825T  + 1584T  - 6237T  + 9680T  - 9009T   + 5400T   - 2057T   + 456T   - 45T
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                                           12
                                                    (1 - T)
```

Can it be displayed as ordinary expression which can be read by computer program? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

There is the `toString` function which you can use.  For example, try this:

```
i1 : QQ[x,y]
i2 : f = x^2 + y^2
i3 : g = (x-y)^2
i4 : toString (2*f - g)
```

and there is also `tex` if you want it in TeX.